# What is the device made from lots of cameras shown in this picture?

Tags: gopro

What is this device that the person is holding as shown this picture, and what is the purpose of such device?

[image]

Comment: It's a (Go Pro?) camera array used to achieve the time slice effect shown [here on 00:09](https://vimeo.com/52330004). However, this makes this question video-related and off topic on the photo SE.

Comment: Thanks Bart Arondson. I thought that the guy is taking a photo using that camera array device. So, that guy is actually taking a movie with time slice effect using that camera array device. At first I thought that that device can take multiple dimensional photos.

Comment: Could be used to create walk-around shots of a static location. Blurs the stills-video line. If used for that it is DEFINITELY not video and has the characteristics of a large stills database. Would also create useful 3D images of a rotated ed in space (up to a limit" object.

Comment: You can do the same thing with photo cameras. An example can be seen in this video: http://vimeo.com/10005245 The resulting "movie" will be of one position that you can rotate or transform in other ways (depending on the position of the camera array, which does not have to be circular). So of course this question is photo related.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Of course it CAN BE video! This video shows the use of a video camera array: http://www.all-things-photography.com/go-pro-hd.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a set of 15 GoPro Hero 3 camera/camcorders on a custom mount.

One of my favorite examples of this in practice can be found in the DC Shoes advertisement videos with Ken Block, who is a professionally rally car driver. Take a look at the usage here in this YouTube video at 06:26, and again at 06:27 - http://youtu.be/btViXvIDsi0?t=6m25s

Here is a further example showing the mount and more details:
http://mashable.com/2013/03/17/gopro-bullet-time/

Of course this mount can be used for both videography and photography, but most often I have seen it used in videography. The GoPro Hero 3 is much better for photography then past models, but it still isn't even close in quality to a DSLR.

For more information about GoPros being used for photography see this previous question:
[How does the GoPro camera perform for photography?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/11720/how-does-the-gopro-camera-perform-for-photography)

Comment: +1 Thanks dpollitt for your comprehensive answer. Now, I know that this camera array can be use for taking photo and also video.