# GoPro Hero6 Linear mode

Tags: image-quality, gopro

I am planning to buy a Gopro Hero6 camera for mainly taking still photos and occasional video. My reason for choosing Gopro is ease of carrying and using it while travelling.

Although i have heard a lot that its not for still images but i see that a new Linear mode has been introduced.
Can someone please guide me if Linear mode will give good still pictures.

Just to add i am a traveller so mainly take photos of Sceneries, buildings, sea etc. and also selfies.

Comment: @scottbb : Thanx. I have edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Liner mode as GoPro calls it isn’t all that new, I believe it’s been out for a year or two on at least some GoPro models.

As for what it does, it’s simply perspective correction. GoPros use fisheye lenses with very wide angles. To produce an image without the fisheye effect, software can be used to correct the distortion and crop the image appropriately. This can always be done post shooting using computer software. The liner mode just takes care of this step for you in camera.

As for using a GoPro for photography, see this existing question - [How does the GoPro camera perform for photography?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/11720/4892)

Answer (score 0):

GoPro can be used for photography too. It supports raw mode and can be post processed. Liner mode exists in the previous GoPro versions too. I have a gopro 5 which is use for taking still photos especially when it is raining as it is waterproof. But you should know the limitations of Linear mode. For instance shooting in raw file is not possible in the linear mode.

Sample image
https://flic.kr/p/ZNtwxG